# How can I change the color of a button in WPF that has its style defined as a static resource?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change the background colour of my buttons when the mouse is hovering on them as it looks horrible in combination with my choice of UI design.

[image: Default style of button]

[image: Button when it is being hovered on]

This seems like something intuitive however I didn't manage to wrap my head around how I can actually do it.

Also, I assume that I will also need to change the colour of the button while it is being clicked. Help with that will also be welcome.

[image: Button when it is being clicked]

**Here is what you can find in the App.xaml file.**

As you can see, I tried using  but that gave me no luck.

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <!--Sets the default colours I will be using for this project-->

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="textColor" Color="#0EFFAF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="backgroundColor" Color="#202223"/>

        <!--Sets the default button style so that whenever I want to add a new button, I don't have to re-write the same code-->
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="buttonStyle">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource textColor}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource backgroundColor}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#0EFFAF"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="100,35,100,35"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseDirectlyOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>

            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
```

**For reference, here is one of the buttons that uses this style (present in the xaml file for the main window).**

```
<Button x:Name="UpdateButton"
                Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}"
                Click="UpdateButton_Click"
                Content="Update "
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="3"/>
```

[I have also tried this but with no luck.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060757/change-the-button-default-highlighted-colour-to-transparent-on-mouseover-xaml-wp)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Took me a while to get this working in the WPF designer and in runtime as well. The difference I notice is that I use `{DynamicResource..` instead of StaticResource. 
Also, try using `Property="IsMouseOver"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mostly on the right track, however I think you're going to need to override the `Triggers` on the `ControlTemplate` level. I modified my own code using your example and found that the mouse over trigger stopped working.

Instead of `<Style.Triggers>` here's the structure you need (based on my own code):

```
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="16" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>

                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#e8e7e7"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#e8e7e7"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#ed0d6c"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#00afdd"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#ff3c8f"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#254c8e"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#ed0d6c"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBCDDEE"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

The way that I came up with this structure was using Visual Studio properties page to generate the style template and then modifying it as I needed.